# CSS formatting/layout of .js jQ Soundcloud Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout

I'm trying to create a custom Soundcloud player, but have maxed out my ability with it.

I simply want to display album art next to the track title and have it scrollable.

Now I've got the tracklist working and I have got the album art to work, but I cannot seem to put the two together in the same scrollable box.

I've attached the .css for the player and the .js for the track listing and album art.

.js - [.js file controlling tracklist and album art ][1]
.ss - [.css file controlling look of tracklist and albumart][2]

Here is a link to the example to see how it looks currently.  http://tranceevents.co.uk/soundcloud-custom-player-master/examples/sc-player-standard.html

I am having trouble with this code that grabs and dispolays the tracklisting / trackname and the album art:

```
// create the playlist
$.each(tracks, function(index, track) {
    var active = index === 0;
    // create an item in the playlist
    $('<li><a href="' + track.permalink_url +'">' 
        + track.title + track.artworks 
        + '</a><span class="sc-track-duration">'
        + timecode(track.duration) 
        + '</span></li>'
    )
    .data('sc-track', {id:index})
    .toggleClass('active', active)
    .appendTo($list);

    // create an item in the artwork list
    $('<li></li>')
        .append(artworkImage(track, index >= opts.loadArtworks))
        .appendTo($artworks)
        .toggleClass('active', active)
        .data('sc-track', track);
});
```

When I try using .css to display the album art next to the title, I get two columns both with a scroll bar because of the `$('<li></li>')`

I know hardly anything about this kind of script so do not really know what else to try.

Please can somebody help? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you
Matt

Comment: tranceevents.co.uk/soundcloud-custom-player-master/examples/sc-player-standard.htm this page is password protected. Additionally, why don't you just paste the relevant parts of your code in the question itself? It would help us to know what you've already tried.

Comment: Okay the password is deactivated.

Comment: Cool ive updated my post to show the code